# ngx-editor error after installing and then starting dev server

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-editor

I wanted to use [ngx-editor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-editor) package in my project, So I installed it and then after doing ng serve getting below errors.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-editor/fesm2015/ngx-editor.mjs 215:43-57
Can't import the named export 'ApplicationRef' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-editor/fesm2015/ngx-editor.mjs 1260:2964-2995
```

and bunch of others errors in terminal and it ends on

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-editor/fesm2015/ngx-editor.mjs
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ngx-editor/utils' in 'C:\Users\Asus\Projects\nsol\ui\node_modules\ngx-editor\fesm2015'
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **    
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'
```

My package.json file is

```
    {
  "name": "nsol",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.13",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.13",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.13",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.13",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.13",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.13",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.13",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^10.1.2",
    "@ngrx/store": "^10.1.2",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^10.1.2",
    "ngx-editor": "^12.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.15",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.15",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.13",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
}
```

I have already tried reinstalling node_modules.

Comment: On that npm page it says "Angular compatibility: Angular 12+" (this is for ngx-editor v. 12, which you're using) Your project is using Angular 9. You may try to install v9 of the editor instead.